# dircolors myfile sets LS_COLORS to empty string in screen

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I have a line in my .bashrc that sets a color-scheme:

```
eval $(dircolors colorfile)
```

This works as expected, setting LS_COLORS with the right string generated from 'colorfile'.

When I use screen, the bashrc file is read again, but I lose my colors.  Testing, I ran `dircolors colorfile` in the commandline in screen, and get

```
LS_COLORS='';
export LS_COLORS
```

I can work-around this pretty easily, but I'm curious what's causing dircolors to act differently in screen vs not.  I thought it just blindly parsed the file and outputed the string.  But it must be checking some env variable or something?

Any clues?  Here's some extra info:
My .screenrc is blank, I'm using gnome-terminal.  Dircolors version is 8.25.

I used the `which` command to make sure I wasn't using two different binaries (I wasn't).  I checked the value of $? after running dircolors, it was 0 in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `$TERM` is different inside screen. Accordingly your `colorfile` file should probably begin with

```
TERM screen*
TERM xterm*
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, older versions of `dircolors` do not support name globbing for the TERM arguments—e.g., `xterm*` is not supported, in which case you must explicitly list every terminal type you want to support (one per line):

```
TERM xterm
TERM xterm-16color
TERM xterm-256color
TERM xterm-color
etc.
```

To quickly check whether your version of `dircolors` supports name globbing, do

```
dircolors --print-database | grep TERM
```

and check for one or more globbed names in the TERM listing, e.g.,

```
TERM *color*
TERM xterm*
```

If you don't see globbed names in the TERM listing—e.g., `*color*`, `xterm*`, etc., then it's likely that version of `dircolors` doesn't support name globbing.